# moving custom font doesn't work

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm trying to move a text via animation using raphael's print(), but it doesn't work:

```
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById("stage"), 640, 480);
var text = paper.print(300, 200, "Test Text", paper.getFont("Yanone"), 50);
text.animate({
    y: 400
}, 1000);
```

Anyone have ideas what I may be missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the `text` function instead of the `print` function if you want to animate it later. I'm not sure why but it works ...

Here is an example with both ways of doing it:

```
var paper = Raphael("canvas", 640, 480);
var fonts = [0, paper.getFont("DIN")];

//using print
var p = paper.print(70, 150, "Custom fonts", fonts[1], 20).attr({fill: "#f00"});

//using text (font-family is the same as in getFont)
var t = paper.text(100, 150, "Custom fonts")
t.attr({"font-family": "DIN", "font-size":50, "opacity": 0.5});
t.attr({"fill": "#000"});
```

And on the second one you can do this for example :

```
t.animate({"font-size":40,"fill":"#0f0"},2000);
t.animate({"x":150},5000);
```

Comment: I tried animating the "font-size" and "x" of "p" but it didn't work.. I could animate the "scale" attribute of "p" but it gives a strange result with each letter's size growing but not the spaces between the letters ...