# How to make text object draggable with RaphaelJS?

Tags: raphael, drag

I'm playing with RaphaelJS, and can't figure out how to make created text draggable? I'm using standard .print function. Any example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i was not aware of using print(),
below is my final code. It should work now: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomen/2SjJz/2/
('...T' is for translate function, don't change it.)

```
var font = paper.getFont("whoa");
var text = paper.print(20, 20, "my text", font, 50);

var start = function() {
    text.oBB = text.getBBox();
},
    move = function(dx, dy) {
        var bb = text.getBBox(true);
        text.transform('...T' + [text.oBB.x - bb.x + dx, text.oBB.y - bb.y + dy]);
    };
text.drag(move, start);
```

Comment: I need Cyphon rendered font, that is the reason why I need to go with print()

Comment: You can registerFont and use it as normal http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.registerFont  I'm not so sure but you can take a look at this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811357/moving-custom-font-doesnt-work

Comment: I'm already using it - so no problem with displaying cufon text. The problem is in dragging that text. Example abowe works, but doesn't work if I use print() command (text is printed out, but you can't drag it).

Comment: Did you see the above link of similar question, They also used custom font both with print() and text().

Comment: Yes I saw that.. and there is some difference in both functions. Following code:

    
    var r = Raphael("holder", 500, 200);
    var text = r.text(260, 100, "Example using text()")
    text.attr({"font-family": "Impact", "font-size":50, "fill":"#fff", "stroke":"#000"});
    r.print(50, 50, "Example using print()", r.getFont("Impact", 50), 50).attr({fill: '#fff', stroke: '#000'});

gives me different result as you can see here (Chrome):
http://i40.tinypic.com/258vxu8.png

Also, the first one is not draggable, while the second is.

Comment: Just tested with more browsers/OS-es - looks like text printed out with print() command is always looking same (I believe there is Cuffon in action). Now, maybe text() command tries to emulate Cufon?

Anyway, the main problem is how to enable drag/drop for text printed with print() command.

Comment: Ok i thought text can do it but anyway print() return a set of all characters. You can refer to drag a set to get more information.

Comment: Ok, it's partially working now - the move is smaller than expected, not sure why (for example, if I move mouse pointer approx 100px, the text will be moved maybe 10px)? Don't understand why, any idea?

Comment: Another question: letters are draggable only if I click directly them - if I click on space between letters, you can't drag them. Is there a workaround?

Comment: well you can draw a invisible rectangle behind that text and make them move together.